# How can I fake a twisted.web.client.Response object for testing purposes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, twisted, twisted.web

I'm trying to write a test for a `Protocol` that expects a `t.w.c.Response` object.  I thought it would be as easy as instantiating the object with the appropriate version string, response code, phrase and `t.w.c.Header` instance, but I'm not sure how to handle the last parameter, `_transport`.

As far as I can tell, `_transport` is where the response body will come from when `Response.deliverBody` is called.  Since this is precisely what my protocol must be able to handle, it seems as though I will need to fake a `_transport` as well (assuming my guess as to the role of this parameter is correct).

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the purpose of the `_transport` parameter?  Is my understanding correct?
2. Assuming my intuition is correct, how can I fake a `_transport` such that I can call `deliverBody` on my dummy `Response`?
3. Is there perhaps a simpler way to get a dummy `Response` object?

Any additional tips and advice are welcome!

Comment: This is kind of the same question as <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386385/how-can-i-write-tests-for-code-using-twisted-web-client-agent-and-its-subclasses>.  I suppose it is possible to use `Agent` *without* using `Response`, but only in the most trivial way.  Any good answer to the other question will include an answer to this question too.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I don't think either of these got particularly good answers...

Comment: Could be!  The *question* is nevertheless a duplicate. :)